# A custom String Builder implementation

Tags: java, strings, array, interview-questions

Two code files below : the actual logic & the test logic.

Core Logic

```
package stringBuilder;

public class NoksStringBuilder {

    //initial capacity
    private static final int INITIAL_SIZE = 3;

    String[] stringList = new String[INITIAL_SIZE];

    //number of strings in the builder currently
    int size = 0;

    //total number of chars in the builder , sum total of length of each string
    int characterCount = 0;


    public void add(String s){
        if(size < stringList.length){
            stringList[size++] = s;
            characterCount += s.length();
        }
        else{
            String[] temp = new String[stringList.length*2];

            for(int i =0 ; i< stringList.length; i++){
                temp[i] = stringList[i];
            }

            stringList = temp;
            add(s);
        }
    }

    public String toString(){
        char[] output = new char[characterCount];
        int outputIndex = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < stringList[i].length(); j++){
                output[outputIndex++] = stringList[i].charAt(j);
            }
        }

        return new String(output);

    }

}
```

Test Class

```
package stringBuilder;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        NoksStringBuilder stringBuilder = new NoksStringBuilder();

        Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = 0;

        while(i != 3){

            printMenu();
            i = Integer.parseInt(inputScanner.nextLine());

            if(i == 1){
                System.out.println("Enter string");
                stringBuilder.add(inputScanner.nextLine());
            }
            else if( i == 2){
                System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
            }

        }


    }

    private static void printMenu() {
        System.out.println("StringBuilder Options :");
        System.out.println("1.Add");
        System.out.println("2.ToString");
        System.out.println("3.Quit");
    }



}
```

Comment: In an interview situation, as on Code Review, you should consider all code to be subject to review. =)

Comment: Fair, i will edit my question.. :)

Answer (score 12):

> ```
> public class NoksStringBuilder {
> ```

When told that something implements `StringBuilder`, I would expect it to implement the same interfaces.

```
public class NoksStringBuilder implements CharSequence, Appendable, Serializable {
```

This way it can be used as a replacement for a `StringBuilder` used in more generic circumstances.

> ```
>     String[] stringList = new String[INITIAL_SIZE];
> ```

You call this a `stringList`, but it's actually a `String` array.  If it were an actual `List`, you could quit mucking around managing capacity.

```
      List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
```

This would push all the memory management off onto the `List`.  But I actually don't think that anything involving `String` is correct here.  More on that later.

> ```
>     public void add(String s){
> ```

Similarly, I would call this

```
    public Appendable append(CharSequence csq) {
```

Then you could use it the same way as with a real `StringBuilder`.  Or you could use it the way you do your method (realizing that a `String` is a `CharSequence`).

All this would make obvious that an array of `String` is not a good way to hold a `StringBuilder`.  For one thing, while it makes for a quick `append` of a `String`, it works less well with letters and you lose the random access aspect.  I'd probably try

```
    private char[] sequence = new char[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
```

That puts more work into `add` but makes `toString` simpler.

```
    public String toString() {
        return new String(sequence, 0, length);
    }
```

Note that `length` is an object field that you'll have to maintain.  It's the equivalent of your `characterCount`.

Note that if you want to implement `capacity()`, you could just say

```
    public int capacity() {
        return sequence.length;
    }
```

Comment: Nice catch to say that i can use a list instead of an array, i was working on ArrayList & StringBuilders & I ended up mixing both :)

Regarding implementing the standard interfaces , i agree that its helpful ; but i really wonder if a Java developer should be expected to know these.

Lastly, char[] won't work because we need a list of strings, unless you meant something else :)

Comment: Your question doesn't say anything about needing a list of strings.  If that's a requirement, then you should have included both that and any other requirements in your question.  As is, your requirement is "alternative to `StringBuilder`" and a collection of `String` is a poor way to implement something described only as an alternative to `StringBuilder`.  Note that I'd probably mention that as a criticism of the requirement if the requirement were included.

Comment: Got your point. But why do you say that we loose the random access aspect with Strings? It internally has an array only.

Comment: @nikel  If I want the 117th character of the `NoksStringBuilder`, I have to iterate through the strings to find the one that contains the 117th character.  Each string itself is random access, but we don't know what string contains a particular character index.

Answer (score 9):

`size` and `characterCount` should be private. I suggest renaming them to `stringCount` and `charCount`, respectively. In the comments, "sum total" is redundant, as is "currently".

`add()` should not need to call itself. Just reorder the statements.

```
public void add(String s) {
    if (need expansion) {
        expand array
    }
    store s
}
```

When expanding the array, use `System.arraycopy()` — it's more succinct and slightly faster than a Java loop.

Answer (score 5):

```
String[] temp = new String[stringList.length*2];

for(int i =0 ; i< stringList.length; i++){
    temp[i] = stringList[i];
}
```

I feel this is the major flaw in your algorithm.

You'd be better off with a linked list - no copying needed to expand the list.

Also, why are you manually copying from the string array when there is `System.arraycopy` to do just this for you? (Granted, I wouldn't use it in an interview either, but that's because the interviews I envision don't give me access to the internet or documentation, and getting the parameters for `System.arraycopy` right is tricky.)

The working of your StringBuilder is correct, though it doesn't offer much in terms of utility. It's not null safe, it's not thread-safe, and it doesn't offer any functionality besides appending Strings. There are no constructors that start with a string or capacity, and add returns void, so you can't chain method calls.

I expect a StringBuilder like this to end up in a utilities package so it is not a major concern, but your instance variables are package-scoped. So other code can violate your internals.

There's also a lack of an API; something which is much needed in utility classes because they're far more likely to be reused.

Comment: its a string builder , so no need to be thread-safe ;). nice point regarding chaining.

A question here, why do you say it does not have an API? Agreed there are no constructor with string/capacity. I have an add() method which might make a very small API..?

Comment: @nikel there is no documentation, `add` and `toString` is only the minimal code needed for the object to actually work - it doesn't have ways to easily use the object. Contrast the standard `StringBuilder` implementation which will tell you a lot of stuff about how to use it.

Answer (score 5):

If you add a `increaseCapacity()` function your code gets easier to read:

```
public void add(String s){
    if(size < stringList.length){
        stringList[size++] = s;
        characterCount += s.length();
    }
    else{
        increaseCapacity();
        add(s);
    }
}
```

Now it's also easier to see that this can be written nicer by inverting the if:

```
public void add(String s){
    if(size >= stringList.length){
        increaseCapacity();            
    }

    stringList[size++] = s;
    characterCount += s.length();
}
```

This also got rid of the recursive call.

**Misc**

- I doubt that your class performs better than simply using `+` to concatenate strings, but I'm assuming it's just for academic purposes.
- Use unit tests to test, it's a lot easier than reading input from the command line.
- `initial capacity` isn't such a helpful comment, as it is just a rephrasing of the variable name; if you think capacity is a better term, just rename the variable.
- `size` isn't really the size of anything, but a count, so I would rename it to `stringCount` (otherwise readers may assume that it is the size of `stringList`; count also fits in better with `characterCount`).
- your spacing is off (you can use any IDE to fix all formatting issues).

Comment: Since Java uses a `StringBuilder` to implement using `+` to concatenate strings, I think your first point is a given.

Comment: Great point regarding using Unit tests to test, reusable & improves unit testing skills!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other feedback you've gotten, I wanted to comment on this:

```
package stringBuilder;
```

Java recommends using an inverted domain name such as `com.example.something` to avoid collisions between package names. I see a lot of code on here like this that I assume (no offense intended) is from beginners that just makes up an arbitrary package name, and I think that's a bad idea. It only costs about $5 - $10 to get your own domain name, but if you don't want to do that you can either use a package name based on a domain you're affiliated with (such as your educational institution, although that wouldn't guarantee no collisions) or you can just leave out the package declaration and leave your class in the unnamed, anonymous package.

Comment: Nice point. Only that this should ultimately end up in a utility library & if i use an anonymous package - nobody would be able to use it